# How do I use the assignment operator *= to multiply a value by ten?

Tags: objective-c

Quite simply:

```
current *= 10;
```

Returns an "invalid operands to binary *" build error.

```
int *current = 0;

- (void)bOnePress:(id)sender {
    current *= 10;
    current += 1;
    [resultDisp setText:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%i", current]];
}
```

Google won't tell me what I'm doing wrong, so I'm asking here. :S

Edit: ANSWERED:

```
int current = 0;
```

Remove the *.

Comment: all those saying *current *= 10, I believe all you're doing is swapping a compile time error for a run time one.  Simply make current an int not a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared your variable as a pointer to memory address 0, not as an integer variable that can be multiplied.

Comment: Oh. I was under the impression *<nameofobject> was how you declared variables in Obj-c. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You declared a pointer to an integer, not an integer. You probably want something like

```
int current = 0;
```

Don't get confused with Objective-C manner to deal with objects. These are always pointers, but an `int` is just an `int`, it's a type by itself. You will only use a pointer to an `int` when you want to reference another portion in memory that contains an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

You're multiplying the pointer by ten, not the value.

it should read:

```
*current *=10;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
*current *= 10;
```